# Barplot using ggplot in R, with fill on two numeric variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider a dataset like

```
EVTY    INJU   FATA  
HAIL    1234   15
thun    1488   34
HEAT    1232   34
```

I want to make a barplot of this dataset using the ggplot function in R. The barplot should have the
EVTY variable as the x axis the fill should be based on INJU and FATA.

I cant't figure out how to do this.

Comment: @ Akash: your feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: @rnso The answer was perfect, thats why i just accepted the answer without further commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
mm = melt(ddf)
ggplot(mm)+geom_bar(aes(x=EVTY, fill=variable, y=value), stat='identity')
```

[image]